# Why does elasticsearch use a rather odd `dot_product` scoring formula

Tags: elasticsearch, vector, dot-product

Looking at the elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dense-vector.html) for a `dense_vector` field type, there is a `dot_product` scoring option which is defined as:

```
0.5 + (dot_product(query, vector) / (32768 * dims))
```

My question is, why is it not just `(dot_product(query, vector)`? Where does the `32768` come from?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Tldr;

Although it is in the documentation of `Elasticsearch`, this formula comes from `Lucene`, which `Es` depends on.

As to why this function is used to compare vectors.

## My Interpretation

The dot product is a sum of product of each components of 2 vectors.
This can mean that the value maybe be huge.
Since we want to compare vectors they want a score, a score with boundaries.

> Dot product score computed over signed bytes, scaled to be in [0, 1].
> [Source](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/cce33b07e4f545ae4442c743c5023df1fb5d8fb9/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util/VectorUtil.java#L262)

Since this kind of vector should only have `signed bytes` ranging from [-128, 127].

Your dot product may end up being a sum of `128^2` = `16384`

In order to scale it over [0, 1].

You would need to `dot_product(query, vector) / (16384 * dims)`.

Except that `dot_product(query, vector)` **may be negative**.

At the moment you are scaling from [-1, 1].

How about scaling the dot_product in [-0.5, 0.5] and adding 0.5.

So you end up with the following:

`0.5 + dot_product(query, vector) / (2 * 16384 * dims)`.

Oh snap ! what do we find ^^:

`2 * 16384` = `32768`